# Running 'diff 'command after the 'find' command

Tags: filesystems, find, diff

I'm running this code on shell

```
mv -f ~/sites/text1.txt  ~/sites/text2.txt;find ~/sites/ -type f -exec sha1sum {} >> ~/sites/text.txt \;diff ~/sites/text1.txt ~/sites/text2.txt;
```

However every time I'm having this error:

```
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

Please anyone figure out how to get this code work?

Comment: `find` is expecting a terminator `\;`. You misplaced it after the redirect `>>`. You should have something like `-exec sha1sum {} \; >> ~/sites/text.txt`

Comment: Thanks for figuring out it. Yes this is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mv -f ~/sites.data/text1.txt  ~/sites.data/text2.txt &&\
find ~/sites/ -type f -print0|xarg0 -0r sha1sum |sort> ~/sites.data/text1.txt &&\
diff ~/sites.data/text1.txt ~/sites.data/text2.txt
```

changes I made: each command is now conditionally executed based on the success of the previous command, don't try to do io redirection from find-exec, terminate find-exec with semicolon (which must be escaped), included sequence number in io redirection, added sort to ensure repeatable order, moved data files out of search target to prevent them from listing themselves.

Comment: Thanks this is great. However I'm trying to compare two text file which contains over thousands of lines with some big web site's file list, so using the 'sort>' command would reduce the integrity of the task?

Comment: depending on your system find may or may not be repeatable, If it is repeatable you don't need sort. I think you will need it or something similar.

Comment: I found the `sort` command s required hear. Addition to this I'm having another problem, `find ~/sites/ -type f -exec sha1sum {} \; |sort> ~/sites.data/text1.txt` command takes more than 20 mnts to get completed. I need to `diff` to be run after that, however currently `diff` runs instantly without listning to `&&`
Is there any solution for this?